# Windows display driver hooking, 64 bit

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, kernel, driver

Once I've written a sort of a driver for Windows, which had to intercept the interaction of the native display driver with the OS. The native display driver consists of a miniport driver and a DLL loaded by win32k.sys into the session space. My goal was to meddle between the win32k.sys and that DLL. Moreover, the system might have several display drivers, I had to hook them all.

I created a standard WDM driver, which was configured to load at system boot (i.e. before win32k). During its initialization it hooked the `ZwSetSystemInformation`, by patching the SSDT. This function is called by the OS whenever it loads/unloads a DLL into the session space, which is exactly what I need.

When `ZwSetSystemInformation` is invoked with `SystemLoadImage` parameter - one of its parameters is the pointer to a `SYSTEM_LOAD_IMAGE` structure, and its `ModuleBase` is the module base mapping address. Then I analyze the mapped image, **patch** its entry point with my function, and the rest is straightforward.

Now I need to port this driver to a 64-bit Windows. Needless to say it's not a trivial task at all. So far I found the following obstacles:

- All drivers must be signed
- PatchGuard
- SSDT is not directly exported.

If I understand correctly, PatchGuard and driver signing verification may be turned off, the driver should be installed on a dedicated machine, and we may torture it the way we want.

There're tricks to locate the SSDT as well, according to online sources.

However recently I've discovered there exists a function called `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine`. It may simplify the task considerably, and help avoid dirty tricks.

My question are:

- If I use `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine`, will I receive notifications about DLLs loaded into the session space? The official documentation talks about "system space or user space", but does "system space" also includes the session space?
- Do I need to disable the PatchGuard if I'm going to patch the mapped DLL image **after** it was mapped?
- Are there any more potential problems I didn't think about?
- Are there any other ways to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It may be that there's a better way of solving your problem with more information about the root problem.

Comment: @Larry Osterman: I'm trying to replace the rdpdd (remote desktop virtual display driver) by something else. It's too long to explain the exact reason for doing this, but this is what's necessary

Comment: IIRC, the remote desktop stuff is all pluggable without requiring driver hooking - I believe that Citrix does this for their remote desktop product (I know that the sound redirection logic is redirectable as of Win7).  Unfortunately I don't know how that's done.

Comment: I think the alternative you're suggesting is something called a mirroring driver. It's used to facilitate remote desktop connections using RDP for example. It essentially allows a new windowing session to exist which applications are connected to and render on. The driver does it magic to reproduce the drawing instructions on a remote client. Google will tell you much more.

Comment: @valdo Did you find a way to load your display driver into a session instead of the standard RDP display drivers? I am trying to figure out how to tell windows to load a different display driver in a different session then the normal drivers that are loaded. What I need to know is how terminal services loads their drivers separately vs the normal console drivers. I have searched for days and can't figure out how to do this and you seem like you have a good idea. I don't need to replace the terminal services DD, I am creating software that needs to load different drivers in a session like RDs.

Comment: @user1632018 The most clean way I've found so far is using `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine` to intercept loading of the video driver dll (not its miniport driver) into the session. If you'd like to hear more details please contact me.

Comment: That would be great. Your profile has no contact info though. I have a few ideas to get this job done, but it would be good to know if you tried them first. Do you have an email I can contact you at?

Comment: @user1632018 Please feel free to contact me via vgelfer@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to disable the PatchGuard if I'm going to patch the mapped DLL image after it was mapped?

To load any driver on x64 it must be signed.  With admin rights you can disabled PatchGuard and I personally recommend using DSEO, a GUI application made for this.  Or you can bypass PatchGuard by overwriting the MBR (or BIOS), although this is typically considered a bootkit - malware.